# CNAME not working in Lightsail Custom Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have a domain named `xyz.com`. Custom domain has the domain in it. It is registered outside AWS and Name Server is pointed to AWS Custom Domain in Lightsail. Here is the setup for it.

1. Lightsail container hosts NextJS.
2. AWS Cloudfront CDN in Lightsail points to Lightsail container. AWS ACM has certificate for 'xyz.com' and `www.xyz.com` and is assigned to it.
3. Custom domain has A record entry for `@.xyz.co` pointed to CDN custom domain name. And a CNAME record for 'www.xyz.com' to `@.xyz.com`.

However, when I try to check for CNAME record in DNS checker, I get the error that no CNAME record exists. Also, [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) does not redirect to `xyz.com`. I am using SEMRUSH for SEO and I kept getting the duplicate meta tag errors that state that `www.xyz.com` and `xyz.com` both have same meta tags.

Comment: `a CNAME record for www.xyz.com to @.xyz.com` ... shouldn't that be `a CNAME record for 'www.xyz.com' to 'xyz.com.'` - i.e. no `@.` and `.` at the end

Comment: yes, its supposed to @. BUt, lightsail takes `@.xyz.com` as a domain to refer to `xyz.com`.